# How to seperate <p> and <a> HTML tags

Tags: html, css

Here is my footer:

```html
<footer style="background-color:#1b1c1f;" class="center">
            <p class="center" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:arial; font: size 24px;">© 2022 Moonlight™ All rights reserved.</p>
            <a href="https://moonlighthq.net/terms.html">
                <p style="text-decoration: none; color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:arial; font: size 24px;">Terms</p>
            </a>
            <a href="https://moonlighthq.net/privacy.html">
                <p style="text-decoration: none; color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:arial; font: size 24px;">Privacy Policy</p>
            </a>
        </footer>
```

My problem is, is that it shows like this: "© 2022 Moonlight™ All rights reserved.TermsPrivacy Policy" on our website. How can I add a " " between the `<p>` and `<a>`. And I did try putting a space in the `<p>`

Comment: Do you have a CSS style sheet attached to this HTML page? it is ***highly recommended*** to use style sheets instead of inline CSS styling.

Comment: No, it is just in the <head>. Sorry I am still learning HTML

Comment: padding, margin, nbsp etc

Comment: It may be worth you reading [How and Why to use CSS style sheets](https://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/what-is-css-and-how-to-use-style-sheets-for-web-design.aspx). Please also note the comments at the bottom `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you use `<p>` your elements will have a break and create a second line. What I would do is use `<div>` to wrap your links. However, you can still use `<p>` and create the layout you are trying to achieve. You will want to put this code into your stylesheet (.css) in the `<head>`

Try this:

```
footer.center a,footer.center p 
{ 
display: inline-block; 
vertical-align:top; 
margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Explain why this works and how this works and you will also need to explain to the OP where to put this code.

Answer (score 1):

`&#160;` is also and alternative to `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

The p tag is a block elememt. You are wrapped the block element with a anchor element. if you would like to have:

1. © 2022 Moonlight™ All rights reserved.
2. Terms
3. Privacy Policy

You can replace the first p tag with a span and

```html
<footer style="background-color:#1b1c1f; padding: 5px;" class="center">
            <span class="center" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:arial; font: size 24px; margin: 5px;">© 2022 Moonlight™ All rights reserved.</span>
  
            <a style=" margin: 5px;text-decoration: none; color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:arial; font: size 24px;" href="https://moonlighthq.net/terms.html">
                Terms
            </a>
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:arial; font: size 24px;" href="https://moonlighthq.net/privacy.html">
                Privacy Policy
            </a>
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` code to add " " to somewhere.